# how to only :include based on a conditional statement

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm trying to grab Posts and only the comments that belong_to that Post based on a conditional:

ie.

```
# Grab all posts but only include comments that have been approved.
Post.all(:include => :comments, :conditions => ['comments.approved = ?', true])
```

Update July 20, 2011 10:11 EST

To clarify, I'm trying to grab all posts and only the comments of that post by a specific user.

```
def grab_posts_and_only_comments_from(user)
   {:include => [:comments], :conditions => ['comments.user_id = ?', user.id]}
end
```

UPDATED JULY 20, 2011 11:34 EST

Answer in the comment of the checked answer.

Comment: it is not a clarifying, but a new question actually :)

Comment: sorry about that. do you know how i could this? I'm open to any suggestions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Post.includes(:comments).where("comments.approved = ?", true)
```

The documentation on this feature is much improved in the EdgeGuides.  Check out Section 12.2  [here](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html).

Comment: Hm this only grabs posts if there are approved comments for that Post.  What about if I want it to also include posts which have no approved comments.

Comment: Really?  Have you looked at the generated SQL?  According to the docs, this method should generate a LEFT OUTER JOIN, which will give you all posts, regardless of whether or not they have comments.  In contrast, using a .join(:comments) would produce an INNER JOIN which would only include posts with approved comments.

Comment: Hm I dont know whats wrong. It is an LEFT OUTER JOIN but for some reason posts without comments that match the conditional aren't being returned...

Comment: I figured out what was wrong. The conditional is removing entries with rows that have a null comments.approved field. it should read:

`.where("comments.approved = ? OR comments.approved IS NULL",true)`

Answer (score 2):

Just add new association `approved_comments`

```
class Post < AR::Base
  has_many :comments
  has_many :approved_comments, :class_name => "Comment", :conditions => { :approved => true }
end

Post.includes(:approved_comments)
# or for Rails 2.x
Post.all(:include => :approved_comments)
```

**EDIT**

```
Post.includes(:approved_comments).where(:approved_comments => {:user_id => user.id})
```

Comment: Sorry, I should have clarified that I'm trying to create a scope that receives a variable.  I made the edit above.